# Magento 1 Updated with php 7.2 does not show products in beckend

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7.2, php-7.1

I updated magento 1 to the latest version 1.9.3.10 and then set the php on the server to version 7.2, I also tested version 7.1, and find that with these versions of php the list of products in the backend is not visible.
 
I add an image.
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare `app/design/adminhtml/default/default` and `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml` directory with original source code.

Also try with enable `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `index.php`

Comment: Hi, I enabled ini_set('display_errors', 1); in index.php and solved it, there is an extension (cartin24) that has not compatible with php7.2.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.9.3.10 does not contain support for PHP 7.2.

You still need to apply the patch for PHP 7.2 as described in https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/PHP-7-2-Support-Patches-for-Magento-1-are-now-available/m-p/106999#M211